# Why won't Exchange 6.5 let me change to native mode?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

I am running Exchange Server 6.5 on Windows Server 2003.

I am building a new server running Server 2008 R2 and Exchange Server 2007.  The Exchange setup says that it can't proceed until the old Exchange server is running in "native" mode.

I run Exchange System Manager as directed, but when I reach the property sheet that tells me I am running "Mixed Mode (can support pre-Exchange 2000 servers)", the button that says "Change Mode" is grayed out.

I am logged in as the domain administrator.

My only guess for this is that Exchange thinks I still have an older server.  I used to have an older server many years ago, but I expunged it quite completely, I thought.

So why is this button grayed out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that Exchange 2007 isn't supported on Windows 2008 R2, yet.

Comment: Nor will it be supported - http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/09/21/452567.aspx If you want to user Server 2008 R2 you will need Exchange 2010 (which will not be released until later this year)

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260781):

Method 1: Manually delete the Site Replication Service from Exchange System Manager

You may be able to resolve this issue if you delete the Site Replication Service (SRS). For additional information about how to manually delete the Site Replication Service from Exchange System Manager, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
329606  (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329606/ ) Cannot use Exchange System Manager to delete SRS from remote computer
Back to the top
Method 2: Use the LDP tool (Ldp.exe) to edit attributes

If you cannot remove the SRS, use the LDP tool to remove the following attributes:

```
* msExchLegacyAccount
* msExchLegacyDomain
* msExchEncryptedPassword
```

Additionally, use the LDP tool to edit the msExchAdminGroupMode attribute by removing its value in the Edit Attribute box.

To edit these attributes, follow these steps.

Warning If you use the ADSI Edit snap-in, the LDP utility, or any other LDAP version 3 client, and you incorrectly modify the attributes of Active Directory objects, you can cause serious problems. These problems may require you to reinstall Microsoft Windows 2000 Server, Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Microsoft Exchange 2000 Server, Microsoft Exchange Server 2003, or both Windows and Exchange. Microsoft cannot guarantee that problems that occur if you incorrectly modify Active Directory object attributes can be solved. Modify these attributes at your own risk.

1. Start the LDP tool.
2. Click Connection, click Connect, and then click OK.
3. Click Connection, click Bind, type the administrator's password in the Password box, and then click OK.
4. Expand the CN=Configuration, DC=Domain, DC=com container.
5. Expand CN=Services, and then expand CN=Microsoft Exchange.
6. Expand CN=Organization, and then expand CN=Administrative Groups.
7. Right-click the administrative group that you want in the left pane, and then click Modify.
8. Make sure that the following text appears in the title bar of the Modify window:
     CN=Administrative Group,CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=Domain,DC=com
9. Type msExchLegacyAccount in the Attribute box, click Remove, and then click Enter.

   10. Click Run to remove the attribute.
   11. Repeat steps 8 through 10 to delete the following attributes:

       - msExchLegacyDomain
       - msExchEncryptedPassword
   12. Make sure that the following text appears in the title bar of the Modify window:
       CN=Administrative Group,CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=Domain,DC=com
   13. In the Attribute box, type msExchAdminGroupMode, and then click Replace.
   14. Type 0 in the Value box, and then click Enter.
   15. Click Run to reset the administrative group.
   16. Quit the LDP tool.

Back to the top
Method 3: Remove the SRS from Active Directory

To remove the SRS from Active Directory, follow these steps:

1. Start the ADSI Edit tool.
2. Expand Configuration Container, and then expand CN=Configuration, DC=Domain, DC=com.
3. Expand CN=Services, and then expand CN=Microsoft Exchange.
4. Expand CN=Organization, and then expand CN=Administrative Groups.
5. Expand CN=Servers, and then expand CN=Server.
6. Right-click CN=Microsoft DSA, and then click Delete.

Back to the top
Method 4: Edit the msExchMixedMode attribute
To change the value of the msExchMixedMode attribute to False, follow these steps:

1. Start the ADSI Edit tool.
2. Expand Configuration Container, and then expand CN=Configuration, DC=Domain, DC=com.
3. Expand CN=Services, and then expand CN=Microsoft Exchange.
4. Right-click CN=Organization, and then click Properties.
5. On the Attributes tab in the Select which properties to view box, click Both.
6. In the Select a property to view box, click msExchMixedMode.
7. Click Clear.
8. In the Edit Attribute box, type False.
9. Click Set, and then click OK.

   10. Quit the ADSI Edit tool.

Comment: >> Method 1: Manually delete the Site Replication Service from Exchange System Manager

That worked.  Thanks!